# Root Security Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

simple question :if you make post route and try to access it from google chrome it give me No Message error 
example :

```
Route::post('/Login', 'User@Login');
```

localhost/Login

if i access it from Postman as post request it give what i want

if i access it from Postman as get request

or

if i access it from GoogleChrome (" which is Get Request ")

it return No message error

what i want to redirect any one try to access any route as get to 404notfound page

attached image for the error
[image]

Comment: The Laravel error handling documentation goes into detail about how to accomplish this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#http-exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that once you set your environment to production, the route will give you a HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed response, not sure how you would change it to a 404.

So in your .env you must set APP_ENV to equal production. Like so:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=[encryption key]
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

---

I haven't tested this but maybe you can set another route for the GET version which would return the 404.

```
Route::get('/Login', function() {
    return abort(404);
});
```